# Scala pattern-match on generics

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I have a list of "string"s (a wrapper around class String, named Str), some of them with mixed traits.
At some point in time I need to distinguish the mixin traits to provide additional functionalities.

My code can be resumed to this and it works fine:

```
case class Str(s: String)
trait A
trait B

object GenericsPatternMatch extends {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val listOfStr: Seq[Str] =
      Seq(
        Str("String"),
        new Str("String A") with A, // Some trait mixins
        new Str("String B") with B
      )

    println("A: " + selectStrA(listOfStr))
    println("B: " + selectStrB(listOfStr))
  }

  val selectStrA: Seq[Str] => Seq[Str with A] = (strList: Seq[Str]) => strList.collect { case s: A => s }
  val selectStrB: Seq[Str] => Seq[Str with B] = (strList: Seq[Str]) => strList.collect { case s: B => s }
}
```

In order to keep the code according to the DRY principles, I would like to generify the selectStr functions.
My first attempt was:

```
def selectStrType[T](strList: Seq[Str]): Seq[Str with T] =
    strList.collect { case f: Str with T => f }
```

However due to the JVM runtime type erasure feature (limitation?), the compiler gives a warning and it does not work, most likely because it will match everything with Object:

```
Warning:(31, 31) abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    strList.collect { case f: Str with T => f }
```

After a few hours of searching and learning, I came up with:

```
def selectStrType[T: ClassTag](strList: Seq[Str]): Seq[Str with T] =
    strList.collect {
      case f: Str if classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(f) => f.asInstanceOf[Str with T]
    }
```

With this method I'm now able to select specific traits like this:

```
val selectStrA: Seq[Str] => Seq[Str with A] = (strList: Seq[Str]) => selectStrType[A](strList: Seq[Str])
val selectStrB: Seq[Str] => Seq[Str with B] = (strList: Seq[Str]) => selectStrType[B](strList: Seq[Str])
```

I believe that there might be a way to improve selectStrType function, namely:

1. Simplifying the if condition
2. Removing the explicit cast ".asInstanceOf[Str with T]", but still returning a Seq[Str with T]

Can you help me?

Comment: I wonder what your use case for this is?  Is there a reason why you would loose the information of what Str is tagged with in the first place?  Can that be prevented?  Using reflection to recover that information is not a very performant pattern.  What are you trying to accomplish with the type tagging?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to remove the reflection, however I was unable to that on my own.

Comment: As for use case, I'm using it currently for a database schema and some columns have special features like: need additional validations or trigger some behavior over those columns. But I want the flexibility of adding a specific feature to a column, but not the other or mix features.
For instance:
Column("column_name") with Required

Comment: Are your traits ever going to be valid mixed in to anything that is not a Str?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your method as follows and it will work.

```
def selectStrType[T: ClassTag](strList: Seq[Str]): Seq[Str with T] =
  strList.collect { case f: T => f }
```

Because of the `ClassTag` context bound a type match on just `T` will work (ideally `Str with T` should also work, but this appears to be a limitation). Now the compiler knows that `f` has type `Str` and also type `T`, or in other words `Str with T`, so this compiles. And it will do the right thing:

```
scala> selectStrType[A](listOfStr)
res3: Seq[Str with A] = List(Str(String A))

scala> selectStrType[B](listOfStr)
res4: Seq[Str with B] = List(Str(String B))
```

EDIT: correction, it appears that this will work **as of Scala 2.13**. In 2.12 you need to help the compiler a little:

```
def selectStrType[T: ClassTag](strList: Seq[Str]): Seq[Str with T] =
  strList.collect { case f: T => f: Str with T }
```

Comment: You should use Manifest instead of ClassTag.  Its preferred and I believe ClassTag will be deprecated at some point.  The code compiles exactly with that substitution.

Comment: @NigelBenns You definitely should not. It's the other way around.

Comment: That is perfect. I can also confirm that your 2.12 code version works in Scala 2.11.X

Comment: While you can make some things like this work using `ClassTag`, you should probably consider alternate designs. Requiring a `ClassTag` means you can only call `selectStrType` in contexts where `T` is concrete, or where you pass the `ClassTag` requirement upstream.